# Deleting records from the server after 15 days

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete uploaded files from the server after 15 days using SQL.

How would I do that? The following is the current code, but it isn't working.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mt","mt");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("mt", $con);

function curdate(){
date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Calcutta"); 
$cd=date("d/m/Y");
}

mysql_query("DELETE FROM mt_upload WHERE DateTime < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
'");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to vote or accept answers yet?

Comment: no help for people who don't actually participate in the site

Comment: no i didnt came to know properly how to do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there may be a date / datetime mismatch in your statement which I've seen act goofy under MySQL.  Try to match date comparison with dates and datetime comparisons with datetime.

Try using now() instead of curdate() and see if you get better behavior.

"DELETE FROM mt_upload WHERE DateTime < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)"

Comment: hmmm thank u very much its working fine for now()....how can i use with curdate() because i want date format in this way for some other work 21/11/2009 in now function date format in this way 2009/11/21

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure cron jobs for that........

you have cron Job in your cpanel setup that.......

configure the timestamps,

set the php file with only delete script no timestamp management.........

may be you can search for CRon job over google......